# PHP readfile from external server

Tags: php, external, readfile

I've got a problem with readfile() from external server. Downloaded file is always broken and has size about 3,4kb. It's working on local host.

1st:

```
$file_name = $_POST['myname'];
readfile("http://www.ftj.eu/.../3n.pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name" .date("m-d-y") . ".pdf");
```

2nd:

Do you know why it isn't working even on local host?:

```
readfile("3n.pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$_POST['myname']" .date("m-d-y") . ".pdf");
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Please help me.

**EDIT:**

help me make readfile from external url working.

Comment: "syntax error" means that you have typed something wrong, and PHP can't make any sense of it. This has nothing to do with `readfile()` or what server you are running it on (though depending on the error, it may sometimes be due to a difference in PHP versions).

Comment: First one is working on local but not with external url.
Second crashes error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error, not a problem with `readfile()` as @Will already mentioned.

Replace this :

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$_POST['myname']" .date("m-d-y") . ".pdf");
```

With this (adding the curly braces around `$_POST['myname']`):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$_POST['myname']}" .date("m-d-y") . ".pdf");
                                                  ^                ^
```

**Edit:**

As for `readfile()` from an external URL, this is what the PHP Manual has to say about it :

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details on how to specify the filename. See the [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

What that means is that you have to enable [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/allow-url-fopen) in your `php.ini` or you can use curl to download the file on your server then serve it to your clients.

**Example using curl :**

```
<?php 
    $remote_file_url = 'http://www.ftj.eu/.../3n.pdf';
    $downloadedFileName = "your_pdf_file.pdf";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remote_file_url);
    $downloadedFile = fopen($downloadedFileName, 'w+');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $downloadedFile);
    curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
    fclose($downloadedFile);

    readfile($downloadedFileName);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$_POST['myname']}" .date("m-d-y") . ".pdf");
```

Comment: Thank you know it's working without $file_name.
But still do not work readfile from external url.

Comment: now that the syntax error is cleaned up, perhaps you should edit your question to focus on the main issue which you are having?

Comment: It depends on your host. Contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your server is set to not open remote files, so you can not use fopen, readfile and similar commands on it unless you change its configuration.

Comment: `fopen(), file_get_contents(), fpassthru(), file()` don't work too
What can I do?

Comment: Contact your host and tell them to enable `allow_url_fopen` in the php.ini file or if you have access to it, refer to the following resource: http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php