# Remove target attribute in iframe link

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, attributes, anchor

I have an iframe on one of my pages that shows content on an external site (vendor product).  All works well except a few links that have target="_main" in them.  These links open in a new tab. What I need to do is strip the target attribute from all links within the iframe so all links stay within the iframe rather than opening a new window or tab.

It seems like there should be a simple javascript solution to this.

If I can't get this to work in an iframe then I will be forced to re-create all the content on my site which would be very painful..... to say the least.

Any help???

Comment: you cant add/change elements in a iFrame, you have to see them like a hole on your site that display some else content, which it can't be modify or change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002867/how-to-force-all-links-to-open-in-iframe

Comment: JavaScrpt can not touch the other domain because of the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

You need access to the external site's codebase in order to dynamically fix this. What you want to do in the external site's codebase is to check if the sites is within an iframe. If it is within an iframe then run a function to remove all target attributes on links.

// vendors product page

if ( self !== top ){

$('a').removeAttr('target');

} // else do nothing

self !== top is the same as saying if my site isn't the top most window then return true.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly that I am aware of.

However, if you have access to a scripting language (like PHP or ASP) on your site you can read your vendors' page directly from your server, do a find & replace on it & then render that onto your site; either in an iframe or however else you want.

**Edit**

There are many ways to do this, depending on how much control you have over you PHP config. Have a look at these resources & see if you can figure out what to do. If not I would suggest you start a new question specifically focused on what it is you are struggling with.

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php With this method you have to be aware of the tip on the page:

> > A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php Again, be aware of the warning & notes.
3. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

I personally have written a class that uses fsockopen because it is the most flexible for my needs but usually file_get_contents does the trick because it is the simplest to set up out of the 3 options, if you have the right wrappers configured & you don't need to start working with SSL or funny protocols. I stay away from CURL because you have to install a library in order for it to work. I prefer my code to be portable for standard installs.

Some useful links that might help:

- [PHP readfile from external server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882878/php-readfile-from-external-server)

**Possible Example**

```
$vendorUrl = isset( $_REQUEST['vendor'] ) ? $_REQUEST['vendor'] : 'www.default-vendor.com';
$iframeContents = file_get_contents("http://$vendorUrl", false);
exit str_replace( 'target="_main"', '', $iframeContents );
```

Then you just have point your iframe at whatever page you save this script in on your server & include ?vender=www.vendor-url.com as the query string.

Comment: I have access to php, but have no clue how I would do this.  Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: @user2494144 Take a look at my updated post & see if any of that helps you

Answer (score 0):

How about giving your own iframe the name _main?

```
<iframe name="_main" ...
```

The other links should then open in that iframe too.

Regards, Max